# PHP preg_replace Strips Quotes

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to strip out any character that is above ASCII 127.  I have the following regular expression which works well except it strips out quotes (").  How can I get the results I need?

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\.\\"\/+() -]/', '', $text);
```

Comment: Your regext works for me and does not remove quotes... https://eval.in/394262

Comment: To strip out any above 127 try `[^\x00-\x7F]`

Comment: This is my code now and it isn't stripping out ASCII 128 and above: $text = preg_replace('[^\x00-\x7F]', '', $text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your regular expression from your regular expression like below:-

```
<?php
    $text = 'daasdsadsdasAAASDSDWEEQE~!@#$$%^%%&^*&()(_()_"';
$text = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\.\"\/+() -]/', '', $text);
echo $text;
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/394254

Comment: quotes are still gone?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the runaround guys but my original code works fine.  I just happened to notice that the quote I was trying to maintain was actually a curled quote which is, of course, one of the extended characters I wanted to strip.  When I replaced that with a regular quote it worked fine.